# PayPal integration in OpenOLAT .properties

Tags: java, paypal, configuration, openolat

I am currently working with a Tomcat based open source software (OpenOlat, https://github.com/OpenOLAT/OpenOLAT) and i am trying to figure out how to get the paypal integration running.

I followed the instruction at the documentation for my paypal business account (https://confluence.openolat.org/display/OO140EN/PayPal+Configuration) and entered my credentials at the admin dashboard.

It seems like that there are two ways to include the credentials. One will be through the admin dashboard and the second through the .properties file.

OpenOlat ist asking me about the following credentials:

> paypal.application.id=
>   paypal.first.receiver.email=
>   paypal.security.password=
>   paypal.security.signature=
>   paypal.security.user.id=

and I am not sure about the application.id they are asking for. Can someone help me to get this running?

Already tried my credentials on another webside to proof if they are wrong.

this is my Error Message i get when i am testing my credentials

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at org.olat.resource.accesscontrol.provider.paypal.manager.PaypalManagerImpl.convertCurrency(PaypalManagerImpl.java:604)    at org.olat.resource.accesscontrol.provider.paypal.ui.PaypalMasterAccountController.checkCredentials(PaypalMasterAccountController.java:256)    at org.olat.resource.accesscontrol.provider.paypal.ui.PaypalMasterAccountController.formInnerEvent(PaypalMasterAccountController.java:241)  at org.olat.core.gui.components.form.flexible.impl.FormBasicController.event(FormBasicController.java:430)  at org.olat.core.gui.control.DefaultController.dispatchEvent(DefaultController.java:206)    at org.olat.core.gui.components.AbstractComponent$1.run(AbstractComponent.java:240)     at org.olat.core.logging.activity.ThreadLocalUserActivityLoggerInstaller.runWithUserActivityLogger(ThreadLocalUserActivityLoggerInstaller.java:108)     at org.olat.core.gui.components.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:238)     at org.olat.core.gui.components.form.flexible.impl.FormWrapperContainer.fireFormEvent(FormWrapperContainer.java:131)    at org.olat.core.gui.components.form.flexible.impl.Form.fireFormEvent(Form.java:717)    at org.olat.core.gui.components.form.flexible.impl.elements.FormLinkImpl.dispatchFormRequest(FormLinkImpl.java:239)     at org.olat.core.gui.components.form.flexible.impl.FormItemImpl.doDispatchFormRequest(FormItemImpl.java:567)    at org.olat.core.gui.components.form.flexible.impl.Form.evalFormRequest(Form.java:296)  at org.olat.core.gui.components.form.flexible.impl.FormWrapperContainer.doDispatchRequest(FormWrapperContainer.java:100)    at org.olat.core.gui.components.AbstractComponent.dispatchRequest(AbstractComponent.java:193)   at org.olat.core.gui.components.Window.doDispatchToComponent(Window.java:1202)  at org.olat.core.gui.components.Window.dispatchRequest(Window.java:398)     at org.olat.core.gui.components.Window.doDispatchRequest(Window.java:282)   at org.olat.core.gui.components.AbstractComponent.dispatchRequest(AbstractComponent.java:193)   at org.olat.dispatcher.AuthenticatedDispatcher.processValidDispatchURI(AuthenticatedDispatcher.java:263)    at org.olat.dispatcher.AuthenticatedDispatcher.execute(AuthenticatedDispatcher.java:184)    at org.olat.core.servlets.OpenOLATServlet.executeUserRequest(OpenOLATServlet.java:269)  at org.olat.core.servlets.OpenOLATServlet.doPost(OpenOLATServlet.java:216)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at org.olat.core.servlets.OpenOLATServlet.service(OpenOLATServlet.java:160)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at org.olat.core.servlets.HeadersFilter.doFilter(HeadersFilter.java:95)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

The paypal.application.id is mandatory, not optional. You need to generate it in the paypal developer UI.

Right now it seams that the application key can not be generated anymore as PayPal changed their API. The only way to get a valid Application ID if you don't have one yourself is to get the Application ID from frentix, the OpenOlat software developer and vendor.

An updated OpenOlat version is in the works that does not require the Application ID, however it is not yet clear when this new version will be released. You can help funding to speed up the development.